# Read images from zipfile fast in python3

Tags: python-3.x, image, zip

I try to load images from a 1GiB ZIP file with JPG images in it.

My solution with `zipfile.open()` is:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import torch
import numpy as np

filepath = "data/file.zip"
list_of_filenames = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg"] # In my actual code filenames are recieved by zipfile.namelist()
idx = 0 # In my actual code I iterate over a batch of images.

with ZipFile(filepath, "r") as archive:
  with archive.open(list_of_filenames[idx]) as f:
    im = Image.open(f)
    img = np.array(im)
    x = torch.from_numpy(img)
```

My solution with `zipfile.read()` is:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import torch
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

filepath = "data/file.zip"
list_of_filenames = ["img1.jpg", "img2.jpg"] # In my actual code filenames are recieved by zipfile.namelist()
idx = 0 # In my actual code I iterate over a batch of images.

with ZipFile(self.filepath, "r") as archive:
  f =  archive.read(list_of_filenames[idx])
  im_enc = BytesIO(f)
  im = Image.open(im_enc)
  img = np.array(im)
  x = torch.from_numpy(img)
```

Both solutions work, the problem is that it takes more than 2 seconds to read a single [218, 178, 3] image! I read multiple times (can't remember sources) that zipfile.read() would avoid extracting the file and therefore be faster, though I can't read that from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.read). Is there a faster way, or must I extract the whole file before iterating through the images?

Comment: It's not normally a good idea to try and zip/compress an already compressed file such as a JPEG...

Comment: Did you try profiling your code? Or just unzipping without creating PIL Images to find what's slowing you down?

Comment: Did you try checking how much memory you are using?